# How to find currently used size of UDP receive buffer in Winsock

Tags: c++, networking, udp, winsock

I have a UDP socket in blocking mode, I have bursts of packets and some are getting lost.

1. How can I find out current used size in receive buffer in winsock?
2. How can I understand whether system is discarding packets?

Comment: How to know whether you're dropping packets depends on what application-layer protocol you have on top of UDP.  What is it?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I am using Datagram sockets via WinSock2.

Comment: Right so what is the protocol?  For example it might be some VoIP protocol, or a video game protocol, or...?  We need to know what is layered on top of UDP because that's where the sequence numbers should be, if there are any.

Comment: Ah ok. It's a proprietary protocol, similar to RTP. It has sequence number inside and using that sequence numbers I detect packet loss. But, how can I understand whether it is an actual loss, or a discarded packet?

Comment: What is the difference between an "actual loss" and a "discarded packet"?

Comment: Actual loss - packet loss due to losses on L1 and L2, alias low network quality. Discarded packet - packet discarded by system, because receive buffer is full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WSAIoctl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passed FIONREAD is documented this way:

> If the socket passed in the s parameter is message oriented (for
>   example, type SOCK_DGRAM), FIONREAD returns the reports the total
>   number of bytes available to read, not the size of the first datagram
>   (message) queued on the socket.

I think this answers your first question.  As for the second, I see no way to programmatically figure that out.  You should use sequence numbers in your application to detect gaps, and then look at the receive buffer size and guess that if it's close to full, the losses are due to running out of buffer space.

Answer (score 0):

The receive buffer size for any socket is given by calling getsockopt() with the  SO_RCVBUF option

I don't see how you can distinguish at the receiver between a packet lost in the network and a packet discarded at the local host. All you can tell is that it didn't arrive, and you need a higher-level protocol than UDP to tell you so, a sequence-numbered protocol with ACKs or NACKs.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear with my question. I was interested in total buffer size, but in currently used buffer size.